# Login failed for user 'domainName\machineName$' When Running Spring Boot App as a Service

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, windows-services

I'm trying to run a spring boot application as a windows service (using winsw for wrapping the jar). The application is supposed to connect to MSSQL DB and it's failing on the following error: 
`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'DOMAINNAME\MACHINENAME$'. ClientConnectionId:95d1d427-ee8e-4811-b7be-411a4a7ce30c`

**When running the application jar from command line everything works perfectly**
The db connection setting are in application.properties file:
`spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`
`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://DB-SERVER:1433;databaseName=db_name;domainName=domain_name;integratedSecurity=true;`

Comment: When executing from the CLI the process is using your own Windows Authentication token and, if it's connecting successfully, then the SQL Server instance has a Windows Login configured for `DOMAINNAME\YourLogin`. Does the SQL Server instance also have a Windows Login configured for `DOMAINNAME\MACHINENAME$`? Does that Windows Login have correct User Mappings so that it can access the `db_name` database?

Comment: If you have access to the SQL Server instance's ERRORLOG look in there for cases of `Error Number: 18456`, take note of the `State` number, and compare the `State` number against those listed at [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error). This should reveal what the actual issue is when the `MACHINENAME$` account is attempting to login.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up replacing the authentication method from windows authentication to sql server authentication with explicit username & password in the connection string, so that sql server access does not depend on the windows login and now it's working.

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://DB-SERVER:1433;databaseName=db_name;user=user;password=password;`